# Drag-drop AS3: how to drag child mc out of parent mc and add to new parent mc

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Here is a working script to drag drop a **ball** from the **stage** into another **target mc**:

```
ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp); 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);     
function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void{ 
    var ballPoint:Point = ball.parent.localToGlobal( new Point(ball.x, ball.y) ); 
    ball.parent.removeChild(ball); 
    addChild(ball); 
    ball.x = ballPoint.x; 
    ball.y = ballPoint.y; 
    ball.startDrag(); 
}      
function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void{ 
    ball.stopDrag(); 
    if(!event.target.dropTarget) { return };      
    var dropT:MovieClip = event.target.dropTarget.parent; 
    var ballPoint:Point = dropT.globalToLocal( new Point(ball.x, ball.y) );      
    ball.parent.removeChild(ball); 
    dropT.addChild(ball); 
    ball.x = ballPoint.x; 
    ball.y = ballPoint.y; 
}
```

It works well but I'm new to AS3 and I am having difficulty amending this script to **drag the ball out of a parent mc** (instead of the stage) and onto another mc (the target mc). To explain: imagine a ball, a box, a tri, + more shapes all within a scrolling mc (initial parent), the user scrolls to select a shape, then drag-drops onto a target mc on the stage.

The scrolling is no problem, but how would you amend the script above so that the ball can start inside a parent mc rather than on the stage itself?

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a solution that works well.
Along the way I also solved a common problem with strict mode and casting (see line 5 & 16 in the code below).

```
scroller.ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp); 
scroller.ball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void  
{ 
   var dragIt:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
   var dragPoint:Point = dragIt.parent.localToGlobal( new Point(dragIt.x, dragIt.y) ); 
   dragIt.parent.removeChild(dragIt); 
   stage.addChild(dragIt); 
   dragIt.x = dragPoint.x; 
   dragIt.y = dragPoint.y; 
   dragIt.startDrag();
}
function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void  
{ 
   stopDrag();
   var dragIt:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);
   if(!dragIt.dropTarget) { 
      trace("you missed");
      return ;
   }; 
   var dropT:MovieClip = event.target.dropTarget.parent; 
   var dropPoint:Point = dropT.globalToLocal( new Point(dragIt.x, dragIt.y) ); 
   dragIt.parent.removeChild(dragIt); 
   dropT.addChild(dragIt); 
   dragIt.x = dropPoint.x; 
   dragIt.y = dropPoint.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things. You don't need to do a ball.parent.remove(ball) call - the next addChild(ball) automagically removes the MC from where ever it is.

In the pickUp() call, do a this.stage.addChild( ball ), to put the ball into (on top of) everything else.

Then in the dropIt() call, do an addChild( ball ) on whichever MC you want to put the ball into...

Comment: Thanks for your help and I've experimented with your suggestions, but none of those ideas address my actual question which concerns dragging the ball *out of a parent mc* rather than *directly* on the stage itself.